# Replacing Western Arabic numerals with Arabic–Indic numerals in formulas

Tags: arabic

Is there a way to use non-Western Arabic digits in formulas of an English tex document? For example in output of

```
$$\frac{100x}{25}$$
```

Arabic–Indic numerals/Eastern Arabic digits (٠ ١ ٢) will appear instead of Western Arabic (0, 1, 2) ones. I'm looking for a way workable with `latex` without using `xetex`.

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$`. Use `\[...\]` instead ;-). Far more important question: What are English digits?

Comment: Is it obsolete?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to for the `$$...$$` issue

Comment: This question is misleading. We tend to name 1,2,3 etc as arabic digits, not as English digits

Comment: I agree with @SoundsOfSilence that the wording is misleading. The [Hindu-Arabic numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system#Spread_of_the_Western_Arabic_variant) was adopted in Europe in the 12th century when al-Khwarizmi's book "Algebra" was translated and so the numbering became known as "Arabic numerals" (as opposed to "Roman numerals") which causes confusion. Perhaps it would be clearer if you replace "English digits" with "Western Arabic numerals" and "Arabic ones" with "Arabic–Indic numerals" or "Eastern Arabic numerals" for clarity.

Comment: Well I do not know what is an exact name for arabic and english digits. btw, if you edit my question I'll accept.

Comment: Okay. I'll edit it. It may help other users with the same question when they search the site.

Comment: BTW I didn't mean to sound like I was giving a lecture. I just wanted to explain why the terms "english digits" and "arabic ones" were causing confusion. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with arabtex package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{arabtex,utf8}   \setcode{utf8}            
\begin{document}
test 
\[\ell+\frac{\RL{100}x}{\RL{25}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[arabic]{babel}` was needed for me. Is there a way to change the digits' font?

Comment: babel arabic have nothing to do here and no arabtex have only this font

Answer (score 2):

for Arabic numbers

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}}
```

for indian numbers

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=machriq]{arabic}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lualatex`:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%   \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}
test 
\[\ell+\frac{١٠٠x}{٢٥}\]
\end{document}
```

But I do not know how to use a specific font for the Arabic. Simply enclosing the numbers in `\arabicfont`(defined in preamble) does not seem to work in the environment.