# Replacing western Arabic digits with Indic digits (eastern Arabic digits) in formulas

Tags: arabxetex

I would like that digits in math formulae appear like ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ rather 0123456789. Hence I would like that for example $2$ appears like ۲

**Note**: A related question has been asked here: [Replacing Western Arabic numerals with Arabic–Indic numerals in formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235063/) but that the solutions there cannot be used here since I don't use `arabtex`, I use `arabxetex`. Also I don't use luatex (I use xelatex for compiling the document), hence the solutions there do not apply in this situation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabxetex}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
\begin{farsi}
$a\sp2+b\sp2=c\sp2$
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```